# Use get_option in WordPress to create new JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I've been building my first WordPress plugin, and I've of course hit some roadblocks. I first wrote all this code as a page template, but now I'm converting it to a plugin so I can use it across several sites.

It's essentially a contact form that creates a price quote based on user selection. When it was a template, I just hardcoded the values and made everything work with an external jQuery file. Now, I'm wanting to take user input from the plugin admin settings page and use *that* value to make calculations rather than the values I hardcoded.

Here's what I had before with the jQuery:

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#carpet_cleaning).change(function () {
              var bedrooms = $("#carpet_cleaning").val();

/*-------CHANGE RATES HERE--------*/
    var total = (bedrooms * 39);
    var totalPrice = "$" + total;

    $("#output1").text(totalPrice).fadeIn();
        });  
    }(jQuery));
```

So basically I want to use user input from the plugin admin settings instead of hardcoding a 39. That way prices can vary depending on what price the user wants to set.

Here's my HTML for my admin settings:

```
  <h2>Display Settings</h2>
      <form method="post" action="options.php">
         <?php settings_fields( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>
         <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-plugin-settings-group' ); ?>

    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" size="3" name="carpet_cleaning_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('carpet_cleaning_price') ); ?>" /><label>Carpet Cleaning Price Per Room</label>
   </fieldset>

    <?php submit_button('Save all changes', 'primary','submit', TRUE); ?>
   </form>
```

I was under the impression that I could use `get_option` to store the user input. If that's the best way to do that, how could I access that value in my jQuery variable?

Ideally I'd want to do something like:

`var sectionalCleaning = carpet_cleaning_price;`

And then just use `carpet_cleaning_price` instead of 39, which would give me the user value.

Is there some way I can do this easily? I'm also going to have to do this on the backend using PHP so that someone can't adjust the values in their browser and the calculation happens on the server, so if you have a solution for that as well, I'm open to that. Go easy on me, I'm a new developer! Thank you.

Comment: If you do it on the server, you don't need the js variable, you can use AJAX. If you want to pass a variable to js, use this when you register your script: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: This is a great way to handle this, thank you. Here's a link to another explanation that I found easier to follow than the Codex: https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Just in case someone happens onto this thread.